# Moving several variables at once to another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `state` in the`App` component, I have 20 variables, for example; I need to transfer 12 of these variables to the `Item` component. Do I have to list them all the way I did below, or can I transfer the whole state ?:

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lrbwav

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3,
      d:4,
      f:5,
      g:6,
      h:7,
      i:8,
      j:9,
      k:10,
      l:11,
      m:12,
      n:13,
      o:14,
      p:15,
      q:16,
      w:17,
      r:18,
      s:19,
      t:20, 
      y:21, 
      u:22,
      i:23
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Item
          a={this.state.a}
          b={this.state.b}
          c={this.state.c}
          d={this.state.d}
          f={this.state.f}
          g={this.state.g}
          h={this.state.h}
          i={this.state.i}
          j={this.state.j}
          k={this.state.k}
          l={this.state.l}
          m={this.state.m}
          n={this.state.n}
          o={this.state.o}
          p={this.state.p}
          q={this.state.q}
          w={this.state.w}
          r={this.state.r} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <item

        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this `<Item {...this.state} />`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 Is it a good practice?

Comment: Actually it's depends. If your child component requires every variable from parent state then it's ok, but if your child component requires few variables only then it is not good idea to expose all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can transfer the state [...this.state] contains all the state values.

Answer (score 0):

more compact way

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3,
      d:4,
      f:5,
      g:6,
      h:7,
      i:8,
      j:9,
      k:10,
      l:11,
      m:12,
      n:13,
      o:14,
      p:15,
      q:16,
      w:17,
      r:18,
      s:19,
      t:20, 
      y:21, 
      u:22,
      i:23
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w, r} = this.state;
    const data = {a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w, r}
  
    return (
      <div>
        <Item
          {...data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <item

        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass props into your constructor.

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: 'React',
          data: {    // Put your data in a object
            a: 1,
            b:2,
            c:3,
            d:4,
            f:5,
         }
        }
      }
      render() {
    const data = this.state.data;
        return (
      <div>
        <Item props={data}

        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            };
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>{console.log(this.props)}</p> // removed item with a lower case
                </div>
            );
        }
     }
```

If you are not going to mutate the information, change Item to a function and pass in props.

```
const Item = (props) => {  
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
          // return props
      </div>
    );
  }
```